# Container: Accessing DB within same VM fails

Tags: docker, containers

I am trying to have my application connect to the Sql Server Express DB, both which are containerized.

When i run my app container in in a separate VM to the db, it connects and all is good.
However if the app container is running on the same VM as the DB container, it cannot connect.

I've tried setting the network mode to host and still nothing.

I got a very simple setup as part of my hands on learning. 
Diagram of setup below.

Model A: Vm to VM - Connection Works

[image: Model A - VM to VM]

Model B: Internal VM - Cannot Connect thus App fails

[image]

I been reading up on docker a bit (running simple docker setup) to try and figure out the problem but no luck so far.

I've also used docker-compose to try and help still no luck.

**Edit 1:**
Commands used.

**SQL Server: as per docker hub instructions**

```
docker run --restart always -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=RANDOMPASS01!' -e 'MSSQL_PID=Express' -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest-ubuntu
```

**AppA**

This by itself works fine in Model A

```
docker run -p 5000:80 -d appa:0.1
```

I've also tried

```
docker run -p 5000:80 --network host -d appa:01
```

Comment: Can you share the docker commands you are executing?

Comment: @EstebanGarcia added

Answer (score 0):

For what I see that you're doing it (starting your app container with net=host) should be working without issues as long as you are using localhost for connecting to the db.

If this is just for testing in your local machine I would suggest start both containers within their own docker network and access the db by container name, you can do it manually or use docker-compose to do it.

Example with docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest-ubuntu
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    environment:
      - MSSQL_PID=Express
      - SA_PASSWORD=RANDOMPASS01!
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    restart: always
  app:
    # You can use this to tell docker-compose to build the image of you app
    # or use a prebuilt image like the db service is using
    image: appa:0.1
    ports:
      - 5000:80
```

Put this in a file called docker-compose.yml and start it with:

```
docker-compose up
```

This will create two containers in the same network, this will provide you as well with a DNS record for each container with the name of the provided service in the docker-compose file, so instead of using an IP or localhost you use "db" or "app".

More info for docker-compose: https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/

The manual way:

```
docker network create mynetwork
```

Run the containers within the network:

```
docker run -p 5000:80 -d --net=mynetwork --name app appa:0.1
docker run --restart always -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=RANDOMPASS01!' -e 'MSSQL_PID=Express' -p 1433:1433 --net=mynetwork --name db -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest-ubuntu
```

In the same way as using docker-compose you can access the db by using the "db" dns record that docker creates based on the name of the container.

The aforementioned DNS records are only resolvable within the containers.

More info on user-defined networks: https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/